# How to calculate an IRmark of an xml document using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am fairly new coding with C#. I would like to calculate an IRmark of an xml file saved on my c drive.

The IRmark calculation is based on the HMRC's specification on https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/hmrc-irmark-generic-irmark-specification

I have found a code online that I could use to do this. I do not know how to direct it to read and convert the xml file on the c drive instead. I will appreciate your help. Thank you

Here is the code

```
        public static string GetIRMark(byte[] Xml)
    {
        string vbLf = "\n";
        string vbCrLf = "\r\n";

        // Convert Byte array to string
        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Xml);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        doc.LoadXml(text);

        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("env", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
        XmlNode Body = doc.SelectSingleNode("//env:Body", ns);
        ns.AddNamespace("tax", Body.FirstChild.NextSibling.NamespaceURI);

        // Create an XML document of just the body section
        XmlDocument xmlBody = new XmlDocument();
        xmlBody.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlBody.LoadXml(Body.OuterXml);

        // Remove any existing IRMark   
        XmlNode nodeIr = xmlBody.SelectSingleNode("//tax:IRmark", ns);
        if (nodeIr != null)
        {
            nodeIr.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeIr);
        }

        // Normalise the document using C14N (Canonicalisation)  
        XmlDsigC14NTransform c14n = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        c14n.LoadInput(xmlBody);
        using (Stream S = (Stream)c14n.GetOutput())
        {
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[S.Length];

            // Convert to string and normalise line endings  
            S.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)S.Length);
            text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer);
            text = text.Replace("&#xD;", "");
            text = text.Replace(vbCrLf, vbLf);
            text = text.Replace(vbCrLf, vbLf);

            // Convert the final document back into a byte array 
            byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

            // Create the SHA-1 hash from the final document 
            SHA1 SHA = SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hash = SHA.ComputeHash(b);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
```

I have tried this code

```
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(@"c:\myfile.xml");
```

but I get an error message

Comment: Is this what you mean by IRMark: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/hmrc-irmark-generic-irmark-specification ? You may want to put a paragraph explaining what you are talking about in your question

Comment: Updated. Thank you

Comment: Try : string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\myfile.xml");

Comment: Thank you jdweng. Your code did not work for me. I was able to get it to work with byte[] Xml = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\myfile.xml");

Comment: I've been able to generate the IRmark with the above code, however this fails HMRC's test. I've checked the code using the provided java app, which generates the same code.  Is there any one that know what I could be doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Facing the same problem myself. I think this c# was adapted from VB. In comparing the two I think I see a bug. The line text = text.Replace(vbCrLf, vbLf); appears twice. The second one should be text = text.Replace(vbCr, vbLf); Where vbCr is defined as string vbCr = "\r"; I'm not posting this as the answer because I don't know yet if it fixes it. VB version here http://blog.kuffs.co.uk/2009/07/calculating-irmark-for-hmrc-gateway.html